# Why the loop is not running as expected?

Tags: batch-file, goto, delayedvariableexpansion

I have folders like `E:\Backups\code\Hazard\test1` ... `testn`

And inside these test folders something like `E:\Backups\code\Hazard\test1\it0` ... `itn`

The root folder is `E:\Backups\code` from where the code runs.

The below code runs on each subfolders and copies `summary.yml` from `it0` folder to latest `it(n)` folder.

Why the code runs just for `test1` folder and then hangs?

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set root=%cd%
for /D %%X in (%root%\*) do (
    echo %%X
    cd  %%X

    for /D /r %%b in (*) do ( 
        cd  %%b

        echo %%b

        for /f "tokens=1,2,*" %%a in ('robocopy . . file.txt /l /nocopy /is /s /nc /ns /ts /ndl /njh /njs ^| sort /r') do set "lastFolder=%%~dpc" & goto :done
:done
        echo Last folder : %lastFolder%

        for /d    %%j in (*) do  (
            if /i "%%~nj"=="it0" COPY %%j\summary.yml %lastFolder% 
        )
        cd ..
    )
)
```

Comment: The GOTO breaks the FOR construct.

Comment: Thanks  Mofi and Squashman for your response. @ Mofi Yesh in my code  everything from for to is on one line, its just when I pasted in this site it splits into multiple rows. I am new to batch programming and its hard to map the style of coding like in VBA or others vs in batch. I'll try to do as you have suggested. Thanks.

Comment: @Mofi, no, everything from **for** to **do** does not need to be on the same line.

Comment: Can someone please help me in splitting the code into required subroutine so that the code works as it is expected? I am going through some tutorials on it as I am new to this batch programming. Thanks

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use a real programming language instead. It would be a much better use of your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main problems in the code:

- If `goto` is used inside a `for` loop, the loop is cancelled
- If you set a variable inside a block of code (code inside parenthesis), to retrieve the value of the variable inside the same block of code you need delayed expansion, enabling it with `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and changing the syntax used to retrieve the value in the variable from `%var%` into `!var!`.

But

- the `goto` can be removed as indicated in the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33296812/2861476),
- the delayed expansion is not needed. Instead of storing the value from the `for` replaceable parameter inside a variable, just use the replaceable parameter

Not tested, but more or less

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem E:\Backups\ code   \  Hazard \ test1 \ it0 ... itn
    rem             ^root     ^ %%X    ^ %%Y           ^ %%~dpc

    for /D %%X in ("*") do for /D %%Y in ("%%~fX\*") do for /f "tokens=1,2,*" %%a in ('
        robocopy "%%~fY." "%%~fY." file.txt /l /nocopy /is /s /nc /ns /ts /ndl /njh /njs 
        ^| sort /r 2^>nul
        ^| cmd /q /v /c "(set /p .=&echo(!.!)"
    ') do copy "%%~fY\it0\summary.yml" "%%~dpc."
```

Being `E:\Backups\code` the current active directory:

- `%%X` will enumerate the folders under `E:\Backups\code` (`Hazard`)
- `%%Y` will enumerate the folders under `E:\Backups\code\Hazard` (`testn`)
- `%%a` executes a `robocopy` command to locate the folder containing the latest `file.txt` file
- `sort /r` sorts the list of files in descending order so the latest file is the first in the list
- `cmd` retrieves and outputs only the first line
- With all the information available in the several `for` replaceable parameters, execute the indicated `copy` command.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about what the line with **robocopy** should do. It looks like this command is for getting name of last subdirectory in current directory.

Perhaps this code works better. But I could not test it.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "root=%cd%"

for /D %%X in ("%root%\*") do (
    echo %%X
    cd "%%~X"

    for /D /r %%b in (*) do (
        cd "%%~b"
        echo %%b

        call :GetLastFolder

        echo Last folder : !lastFolder!

        for /d %%j in (*) do (
            if /i "%%~nj"=="it0" copy "%%j\summary.yml" "!lastFolder!"
        )
        cd ..
    )
)
goto :EOF

:GetLastFolder
for /f "tokens=1,2,*" %%a in ('robocopy . . file.txt /l /nocopy /is /s /nc /ns /ts /ndl /njh /njs ^| sort /r') do set "lastFolder=%%~dpc" & goto :EOF
goto :EOF
```

It is at least necessary to reference environment variable `lastFolder` with exclamation marks instead of percent signs to really use delayed expansion as needed here.

`goto :EOF` exits the subroutine resulting in continuing on line below `call :GetLastFolder`.

There is one more `goto :EOF` or alternatively `exit /B` after main code necessary to avoid that the code of the subroutine is executed once more after most outer **for** loop finished. This `goto :EOF` results in exiting the processing of this batch file.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there at least the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `set /?`

Comment: @ MC ND you rock ! :) Solved my problem again. Thanks Mofi for giving your time. Appreciate it. MC ND's code works for me and solved my current problem. learning new things. Thanks ton you guys :)

Comment: @ Mofi, you code also works. Thank you all for the help.