# batch file nested if statment crashes

Tags: batch-file, nested-if

I am trying to learn batch by writing simple programs, but I had a problem that is completely stopping me. I figured out that it kept crashing on the nested if statements, but as soon as I removed the nested part, it worked fine.

```
set questionNumber=1
if %questionNumber%==1 (
    set /p answer=Test?
    if %answer%==yes (
        echo hi
    )
)
pause>nul
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable is not set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33442530/variable-is-not-set)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set questionNumber=1
if %questionNumber%==1 (
    set /p answer=Test?
    if !answer!==yes (
        echo hi
    )
)
pause>nul
```

[**Delayed expansion**](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)